# Socketcan and Qt on raspberry pi

Tags: qt, can-bus

Is there a prebuild serialbus library for Raspberry Pi? I would to use 
[QtCanBus](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcanbus.html) in a project. 
Unfortunately I cannot find any reference for installing the necessary library.
tried

```
sudo apt-get install qt5serialbus5
```

without any success..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally managed to solve my problem by using a prebuilt set of libraries from here: https://github.com/tranter/raspberry-pi-qt-builds/releases
With some **ldconfig** magic I managed to link everything together and even launch the example SerialBus app from QtCreator.

Answer (score 1):

To compile and run Qt5 applications for the Raspberry Pi you either need to [cross-compile](https://wiki.qt.io/Raspberry_Pi_Beginners_Guide) them, or setup your Raspberry Pi to [natively run qmake and make](https://wiki.qt.io/Native_Build_of_Qt5_on_a_Raspberry_Pi).

Comment: This is strange because I'm able to compile a qwidget application by just installing the prebuild libraries.